# HTML: Keep checkbox and associated text together while its container is resized

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox, positioning

I have an ASP.Net page which renders checkboxes as below

[image: Elements on same line]

But when I re-size the screen, the controls are crammed together and the checkboxes & their associated text move into different lines and it wouldn't make much sense.

[image: Elements on different line]

I would like to know if there is a way to keep the checkboxes together.

Heres the Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpFiles" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Files") %>' OnPreRender="rpFiles_PreRender" >
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phFile" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbVisibility" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0} ({1})", Eval("FileName"), Eval("FileType").ToString().ToUpper()) %>' Checked='<%# !((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsHidden")) %>' />
              <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFileID" Value='<%# Eval("FileID") %>' runat="server" />
       </asp:PlaceHolder>                            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your input guys. Tried working on your lines. `width` and `min-width` were not working but the idea of `div` was important, +1 for that.
I have used this instead

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phFile" runat="server">
    <div style="display:inline-block; padding-right:15px"><asp:CheckBox ID=...
```

and that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have code

`<!--CheckboxCatering Order(PDF)--!>`

Then update your code like

`<div style="width:300px;"><!--checkboxCatering Order(PDF)--!></div>`

It will solve your problem

Comment: in `asp.net` they are not supposed to use `input` tag directly; instead there is a custom control called `CheckBox` or `CheckBoxList`. However, while rendering they will render as html control only.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a CheckBoxList then the width must be constrained somehow? Set a fixed width to prevent the collapse.

```
<div style="min-width:600px;">
    <!-- check boxes ->
</div>
```

Note that this width is just arbitrary; play around with it...

UPDATE: now that I see your markup, just set a width on the repeater.